# Unable to find entity while under a transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm having an issue with this data layer method

```
    public async Task<(bool HasFailed, IList<string> ErrorMessages)> ApproveBillCancelRequest(IEnumerable<string[]> billsToApprove,
        string userId, string operationId)
    {
        var callerInfo = Shared.CommonAcross.Helper.GetCaller();
        InfoScope($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Started", operationId, userId);

        var errorMessages = new List<string>();

        using (var context = new FocusConnection())
        {
            var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                foreach (var billToApprove in billsToApprove)
                {
                    var targetBillNumber = billToApprove[0];
                    var targetPayModeId = int.Parse(billToApprove[1]);

                    var entityBill = context.BILL_INFO_CANCEL_REQUESTS
                        .SingleOrDefault(where =>
                            where.BILL_NUMBER == targetBillNumber &&
                            where.PAY_MODE_ID == targetPayModeId);

                    if (entityBill == null)
                    {
                        errorMessages.Add($"Bill #{billToApprove[0]}, payment #{billToApprove[1]} was not found for cancel approval");
                        continue;
                    }

                    entityBill.BILL_INFO.LAST_MODIFIED_BY = userId;
                    entityBill.BILL_INFO.STAMP_DATE = DateTime.Now;
                    entityBill.BILL_INFO.INPUT_STATUS = 0;

                    var cancelledBill = new BILL_INFO_CANCELED
                    {
                        BILL_NUMBER = entityBill.BILL_NUMBER,
                        PAY_MODE_ID = entityBill.PAY_MODE_ID,
                        CASHIER_ID = entityBill.CASHIER_ID,
                        CANCELED_DATE = entityBill.CANCEL_REQUEST_DATE,
                        CANCEL_REQUESTED_BY = entityBill.CANCEL_REQUESTED_BY,
                        CANCEL_APPROVED_BY = userId,
                        REMARKS = entityBill.CANCELATION_REASON
                    };

                    // Add cancelled bill
                    context.BILL_INFO_CANCELEDS.Add(cancelledBill);

                    // Remove cancellation request
                    context.BILL_INFO_CANCEL_REQUESTS.Remove(context.BILL_INFO_CANCEL_REQUESTS.Single(where =>
                        where.BILL_NUMBER == cancelledBill.BILL_NUMBER && where.PAY_MODE_ID == cancelledBill.PAY_MODE_ID));

                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                transaction?.Rollback();

                ErrorScope($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Exception [{exp.Message}]", exp, operationId, userId);
                errorMessages.Add($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Exception [{exp.Message}]");

                return (true, errorMessages);
            }
        }

        return (errorMessages.Any(), errorMessages);
    }
```

The issue is that in the ForEach loop, the first record is retrieved properly and processed. But the remaining records are never found (`entityBill == null`) but they are in the database. I believe it has something to do with the running transaction.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

This was a hard one to crack. It turns out that while String.Splitting() on the UI layer, there was an extra space being appended to the first index of the array within the List of arrays. So I fixed that by:

```
var targetBillNumber = billToApprove[0].Trim();
var targetPayModeId = int.Parse(billToApprove[1].Trim());
```